# SQL Server: how to delete xml node by sql variable?

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

My first question on Stack Overflow :)

I have XML:

```
DECLARE @xml XML = '<root><tag1 /><tag2 /></root>';
```

I need to remove node, but, path to node is variable "@path".

```
DECLARE @path XML = '/root/tag2';
```

My query is:

```
SET @xml.[modify]('delete sql:variable("@path")');
```

But, I get error:
*Msg 9342, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
XQuery [modify()]: An XML instance is only supported as the direct source of an insert using sql:column/sql:variable.*

So my question is: **how can I delete xml node by sql parameter?**

Comment: You cannot use a variable for the XPath, but you can use various predicates. Please provide more information about your *real-world-needs*... Just to mention: There is a way via *dynamically created SQL* and `EXEC()`...

Comment: Its complex to describe, just created simplified example. I have more requirements here: one is to keep same session. So, dynamic sql is last option to use. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no general recipie...

Just some ideas:

If you know the node's name

```
DECLARE @xml XML = '<root><tag1 /><tag2 /></root>';
DECLARE @nodeToDelete VARCHAR(100)='tag2';
SET @xml.modify('delete (/root/*[local-name()=sql:variable("@nodeToDelete")])[1]');
SELECT @xml;
```

If you know the node's name with FLWOR-query

```
DECLARE @xml XML = '<root><tag1 /><tag2 /></root>';
DECLARE @nodeToDelete VARCHAR(100)='tag2';
SET @xml=@xml.query('<root>
                     {
                     for $nd in /root/*[local-name()!=sql:variable("@nodeToDelete")]
                       return $nd
                     }
                     </root>');
SELECT @xml;
```

dynamically created

```
DECLARE @xpath VARCHAR(100)='/root/tag2';

DECLARE @command VARCHAR(MAX)=
'DECLARE @xml XML = ''<root><tag1 /><tag2 /></root>'';
 SELECT @xml;
 SET @xml.modify(''delete ' +  @xpath + ''');
 SELECT @xml';

PRINT @command;
EXEC(@command);
```

Comment: At last, I used dynamic way. Thanks.